# Telegram Bot API - ForceReply with Custom Keyboard

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

From reading the Telegram Bot API i understand it is only possible to either have a **ForceReply** or **Custom Keyboard**. Not both at the same time.

But how can i know if the user's input from Custom Keybord is a reply to the bot's message?

I have this code (PHP) running:

```
apiRequest ( "sendMessage", array (
        "text" => "Choose option",
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'reply_markup' => $keyboardOptions 
    )
);
```

resulting in this:

[image: screenshot]

I know i can get the content of clicked button, but the field "**reply_to_message**" is missing (because it's no reply).

How is PollBot pulling this off? Looks like a ForceReply together with Custom Keybord?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you still need the answer?

Comment: Sure. I did not find a solution since.

Comment: Sorry but I really didn't get what you are mentioned about poll bot. would you please contact me on Telegram? @GameO7er is my Telegram account or you can share yourself , after I get what you are talking about I can answer you